# Specific orientation for different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I want to change screen orientation for each fragment independently in my app (i.e. fragment A is landscape only and fragment B is portrait only) just like I can do that for activities using AndroidManifest.xml.

When I create my fragments I pass a scecific screen orientation constant for each fragment using `Fragment.setArgunents(..)`.

I am switching fragments in base activity like that:

```
public void setCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        if (addToBackstack)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Integer.toString(fragmentCount++));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I have tried changing orientation to the one stored in the fragment's arguments inside `setCurrentFragment`, in `onResume`, `onCreate` methods of fragment using `setRequestedOrientation` every method caused infinite loop with changing orientations (whole activity was destroyed and recreated again and again).

Does anyone knows a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to do this is to store current orientation somewhere else (for example as static variable) to check which orientation was set before activity was recreated and in each fragment check if it is the last one in the stack using `getFragmentManager().getFragments()`

following code works fine for me (my getArguments Bundle content is a few Strings):

```
private static int orientation;

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    Fragment lastFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragments().get(getFragmentManager().getFragments().size() - 1);
    if (lastFragment != null && lastFragment.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
        if (lastFragment.getArguments() != null && getArguments() != null) {
            if (lastFragment.getArguments().toString().equals(getArguments().toString())) {
                setCurrentOrientation(fragmentOrientation, getActivity());                  
            }
        }
    } else {
        setCurrentOrientation(contentPage, getActivity());
    }
}

private void setCurrentOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation == currentOrientation) {
        return;
    } else {
        currentOrientation = orientation;
    }
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(currentOrientation);
}
```